# jquery slidetoggle issue

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, slidedown, slideup

i'm having problems with toggling the next div. heres the code:

[jsfiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/asafche/rnqHk/)

what i need to do is: after clicking the next button, it will close the current box_content and open the next one in the order. simple but i can't do it... please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(".box_next").click(function() {
        $(".box_content").slideUp();
        $(this).parents(".box").next().find(".box_content").slideDown("fast");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your $('.box_next').click() function to this:

```
$(".box_next").click(function() {
    $('.box_content').slideUp();
    $(this).parent().parent().next().children(".box_content").slideDown("fast");
});
```